# Input Box value used in IF code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column (W:W) that shows the year something takes effect. I am writing simple VBA code to identify which rows of clients require "checking" because their effective date is greater than or equal to the year we are currently reviewing. I don't want to have to edit the VBA code each year so I've inserted an input box that I want to use later in the IF statement to flag the clients that need "checking". I keep getting "application-defined or object-defined error". Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
'Ask question for year of testing
Worksheets("Plan_Data").Activate
Dim TestingYear
TestingYear = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which plan year end are you looking at (year only?)")

Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(W2>= & TestingYear &,""CHECK"","""")"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Few questions to clarify.  How is your data stored?  You'll want to build a conditional in VBA rather than setting a cell formula to an IF statement.  Messy and not necessary.  Is the location of the year data changing?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(W2>= " & TestingYear & ",""CHECK"","""")"
```